# Error 403 al insertar evento mediante Google Calendar Api en c#

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar

En un proyecto .net estoy intentando ingresar un evento con participantes mediante la api de google calendar v3. Puedo añadir eventos sin problemas, pero al momento de querer añadir participantes, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Calendar usage limits exceeded. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Calendar usage limits exceeded.] Location[ - ] Reason[quotaExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]
]
```

Esto siendo que no he realizado ninguna solicitud anterior(he probado creando nuevas cuentas de gmail y enlazado sus respectivos calendarios y también activado sus credenciales de uso para esta api), ni tampoco he añadido más de 5 eventos.

Acá el código con el cual creo los eventos:

```
public class CalendarQuickstart
{
    private string jsonFile { get; set; }
    private string RutaCredentials { get; set; }
    private string calanderId { get; set; }

    public CalendarQuickstart()
    {
        RutaCredentials = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rutaCredentials"];
        jsonFile= "credentials.json";
        calanderId = "9cp270uok8t0tq2uss3qb54dos@group.calendar.google.com";
    }

    static List<Event> DB = 
         new List<Event>() {
            new Event(){
                Id = "eventid" + 3,
                Summary = "Google I/O 2015",
                Location = "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
                Description = "A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.",
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 09, 29, 15, 30, 0),
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",
                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 09, 30, 15, 30, 0),
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles",
                }
                ,
                  Recurrence = new String[] {
                      "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO"
                  }
                 ,
                Attendees = new EventAttendee[] {

                    new EventAttendee() { Email = "gustavooguedareyes@gmail.com"}
                }
            }
         };



    public async Task crear_evento()
    {

        string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };

        ServiceAccountCredential credential;

        string filePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(RutaCredentials + jsonFile);

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var confg = Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<JsonCredentialParameters>(stream);
            credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(confg.ClientEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = Scopes
               }.FromPrivateKey(confg.PrivateKey));
        }

        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
        });


        var myevent = DB.Find(x => x.Id == "eventid" + 3);

        var InsertRequest = service.Events.Insert(myevent, calanderId);

        try
        {
            InsertRequest.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                service.Events.Update(myevent, calanderId, myevent.Id).Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert/Update new Event ");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.Read();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("can't Insert/Update new Event ");

            }
        }



    }
}
```